# Spring Boot JMS: access receiveMessage() result via a (RxJava) subscription?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, spring-jms

How can I access a JMS message receipt with e.g. 'receiveMessage( )' in a RxJava subscription like manner?

I don't want to do this in a callback style. I want to have the details of the implementation, like @JmsListener, to be hidden from the caller.

For example, I have a typical method called when there is a message available at a JMS queue.

```
@JmsListener(destination = "mailbox", containerFactory = "myFactory")
public void receiveMessage(Email email) {
    logger.info("Received <" + email + ">");
}
```

How can I access available messages via a (RxJava) subscription?

```
receiver.subscribe( message -> { ... });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a RxJava Subject. I know that Observables are a bit better.

```
PublishSubject<String> source; = PublishSubject.create();

public PublishSubject<String> getMessages() {
    source = PublishSubject.create();
    return source;
}

@JmsListener(destination = "mailbox", containerFactory = "myFactory")
public void receiveMessage(Email email) {
    logger.info("Received <" + email + ">");
    source.onNext( email.getmessage());
}
```

Give the consumer the Subject. It could call:

```
source.subscribe( f -> System.out.println( "Subscriber1: " + f));
```